# How do I take out Pipes?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

For one of the tour challenges, it says to "take out 3 Pipes". If I just run into them, I slow down and that doesn't count. I can hit them with shells, but that doesn't seem to count either. How do I take out the Pipes for this challenge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides frenzy, you can destroy pipes with Bowser's shell (Bowser, Dry Bowser and Bowser Jr. have access to it) or simply get a mega mushroom and ram into a pipe. I've found that I get Bowser's shell way more often than mega mushrooms, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 6):

Have a frenzy and ram into them.

There are probably other ways but thats how I do this challenge.

So find a course with pipes (the SNES Mario race and Toad's race do have them) and find a character that you've got a 3 items per box with, and then just play it a few times. When you get a frenzy, just go ram some pipes.